# Select Tag not opening in Typeahead.js

Tags: javascript, select, typeahead.js

I want to add a HTML *select element* in **Typeahead.js** list. My Problem is that after appending to the list the select element is *not opening* with a *click.* It is opening using **keydown** in keyboard. How I can open the select list in the typeahead
after clicking it.

Here is my code
I am using javascript for **appending** a div containing select Field to the *Typeahead list*

```
    var iFrameDocument = $('#editorArea-frame')[0].contentDocument;

    //selecting the typeahead List using its classname
    var typeaheadlist = iFrameDocument.getElementsByClassName("tt-menu");

     //I am using an iframe in which we have typeahead List with class Name tt-menu
     var iFrameDOM = $("iframe#editorArea-frame").contents();

    //Creating a drug div to be appended to the Typeahead List
    var drugDiv = document.createElement("div")
    drugDiv.className = "drugDiv";


    //Data to be loaded in the selection List 
    var prescriptionFrequenciesData = [  {
            "value": "qMWF",
            "title": "Every Monday, Wednesday and Friday",
            "id": "162256"
        },{
            "value": "q72h",
            "title": "Every seventy-two hours",
            "id": "162255"
        },{
            "value": "q48h",
            "title": "Every forty-eight hours",
            "id": "162253"
        }
    ]

    //List element in which select field is added
    var listElement = document.createElement("li");
    listElement.id = "listToAdd";


    //Input Field for Frequency
    var inputFieldForFrequency = document.createElement("select");
        inputFieldForFrequency.id = "frequencyList";
        inputFieldForFrequency.style.color = "black";
        inputFieldForFrequency.style.width = "auto";
        inputFieldForFrequency.style.marginLeft = "1px";
        inputFieldForFrequency.style.marginRight = "1px";
        inputFieldForFrequency.style.padding = "1px";
        inputFieldForFrequency.style.border = "solid 1px #c9c9c9";

    //Adding values to the Option List
    var start = '<option value="">Select Frequency</option>';
    var len = prescriptionFrequenciesData.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                start += '<option value="' + prescriptionFrequenciesData[i].value + '">' + prescriptionFrequenciesData[i].title;
        }

    inputFieldForFrequency.innerHTML = start;

    //Appending selection Field in inputFieldForFrequency
    listElement.appendChild(inputFieldForFrequency); 

    //Appending list to the drugDiv
    drugDiv.appendChild(listElement);

    //Appending drugDiv to the TypeheadList
    typeaheadlist[0].prepend(drugDiv);


    //Inorder to fucus the selection list i use below code
    inputFieldForFrequency.addEventListener('click', function(){
                console.log('Frequency List Clicked');
                inputFieldForFrequency.focus();
                iFrameDOM.find('.tt-menu').show(); //As i focus the select Field typeahead List gets hidden
                                                   // I have to explicitly open the List
                inputFieldForFrequency.focus(); //
            });
```

My structure DOM is as Folows:-

1. iframe(id:editorArea=frame)
2. div(id:editorDiv)
3. div(class:tt-menu) -->twitter Typeahead.js

iframe contains editorDiv and it contains the tt-menu.

here is the screen shot
[typeaheadList with select Field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5KV1.png)

Now when I press keyboard keydown after clicking on the List it opens but not with click only. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8mU6.png)

Comment: Actually opening the select element would show a dropdown and steal focus from the text field typeahead.js is meant to be used with (where you type which tag/whatever you wish to select). You will need to replace the select element with something else.

Comment: Any suggestion which html element I should use. As you see from the Screenshot, I am able to open the select tag using keyboard down, any idea why it is happening.

Comment: I just understood that the select element appear in the list of typeahead results. If on click you don't `preventDefault` and maybe also `stopPropagation` on the event, the click may continue to propagate and prevent the select's dropdown from being opened. In general, typeahead probably attaches click handlers to its items because clicking an item is intended to accept the typeahead suggestion. That's a general danger of mixing your own UI into UI managed by something like typeahead and the simplest way is usually to avoid doing so instead of trying to counteract all the effects.

Comment: In case any one come across this issue. Now I am using DataList Tag. It is opening in the TypeaheadList.